# fetch data from google sheet to telegram bot

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

i'm new to google app script trying to make a telegram bot to googlesheet.

case :

i successfuly make a script which can add data to telegram app to google sheet (by certain command)

[inputting data from telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITnfP.png)

[here's the data in google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxaEU.png)

however i need the bot to reply me with a google sheet generated code (in row A, "FPB261222-1") after 3 second maybe.. for user to track the status.

what is the script?

Answer (score -1):

I check some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column) and make a one for myself.
This function find a last row in column A on your sheet and then get a cell value. I call sheet by name, you can change it to current list or ID.

```
function test() {
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
  const lrow = sh.getLastRow();
  const Avals = sh.getRange("A1:A"+lrow).getValues();
  const Alast  = lrow - Avals.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='');
  const Alastvalue = sh.getRange(`A${Alast}`).getValues();
  Logger.log(Alastvalue);
}
```

And you can sent it to the bot with:

```
sendText(Id, Alastvalue);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).